# 'List' of Properties in NLA Strip Pt.1

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties, nla-editor

[image: NLA Editor page, clicked in an NLA Strip; inside the Strip settings panel there's two custom UI elements: a 'UI List' with two 'custom settings' underneath. Changing the custom settings underneath changes what's displayed in the UI List]

I've got this UI element, outlined in red in the image, in the NLA Editor. I can make the UI elements, but I need help with the logic.

1. How can the 'UI List' contain just the two custom properties shown beneath it, rather than a reference to materials or whatever, and allow them to be edited and updated/saved?
2. Please See Pt.2 at: ['List' of Properties in NLA Strip Pt.2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249080/list-of-properties-in-nla-strip-pt-2)

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: perhaps [this tutorial](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-uilists-in-blender/) will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is adapted from [*Using UILists in Blender*](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-uilists-in-blender/)

One way is to create a class that holds the custom properties for each list item. Each item should have a name, so you might want a class with three items in it:

```py
from bpy.props import StringProperty, FloatProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup

class ListItem(PropertyGroup):
    """Group of properties representing an item in the list."""

    name: StringProperty(
           name="Name",
           description="A name for this item",
           default="Untitled")

    custom_prop_1: FloatProperty(
           name="Custom Property 1",
           description="a floating point property",
           default=0.0)

    custom_prop_2: StringProperty(
            name="Custom Property 2",
            description="a string property",
            default="")
```

To make the class available, put it in a collection

```
from bpy.props import CollectionProperty

# Add this line to the register function
    bpy.types.Scene.my_list = CollectionProperty(type = ListItem)
```

where the `Scene` might not be the correct type to attach the list to but works for a demonstration.  Because you want users to be able to modify the list you'll also want an index property, so add this line to the register function:

```py
    bpy.types.Scene.list_index = IntProperty(name = "Index for my_list",
                                             default = 0)
```

Where, again, `Scene` might not be the correct type.  More about that in part 2.

To allow users to edit the list, you need a 'widget' (UIList subclass) and a couple of operators, one to add items and one to delete them.  Since you've said you know the UI part, I won't paste the ones from the Sinestra tutorial, but the key is that the add operator calls `context.scene.my_list.add()` and the remove operator calls `context.scene.my_list.remove()` from their `execute` routines.

The 'widget' you have in your screenshot has those functions, along with the buttons needed to move items around in the list; so I won't elaborate further.

Comment: Thank you, Marty. I'll try it out.

Comment: Took a while to figure it out but today I got it almost working. Thank you for the help, your explination really did help me see how all the parts connect together.